# Change letters of a string at certain points

Tags: java, string

I get a string from the keyboard and I want every 3 letters in the string to change the original letter to an "X", but I'm having trouble doing this algorithm.

for example: if I have the string **abcdefghij** I have to return the string **abXdeXfgXij**
or if i have **hellokit** string i need to return **heXloXit**

I've done this so far:

```
String ans = "";
String a = "abcdefghijk";
              
for (int j = 0; j < a.length(); j += 3) {
    ans += a.substring(j, j+2) + x;
}
```

but it can happen to give the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` error.

how can i do this without resulting in error?

Comment: I would have called `toCharArray` then changed every third index in that array to `'X'` then constructed a new string from that array

Comment: If the input string is **abcdefghij** then shouldn't the output string be **abXdeXghXj** (rather than `abXdeXfgXij`) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this works fine for me

```
String ans = "";
String a = "abcdefghij";
for(int i = 1; i<=a.length(); i++) {
    if(i%3==0) {
        ans += "X";
    } else {
        ans += a.charAt(i-1);
    }
}
System.out.println(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation doesn't work optimally because of string is copying on every step of the loop, consider using `StringBuilder`.

To solve your problem, just iterate on every char of the input string and copy every char to the output string builder, except for every third character (the character which index `i` satisfies the equality `i % 3 == 2`).

You will get something like this:

```java
String input = "abcdefghijk";
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 2) {
        output.append("X");
    } else {
        output.append(input.charAt(i));
    }
}
String ans = output.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and shorter use regex:

```
String a     = "abcabcabcab";
String regex = "(..)(.)";
String ans   = a.replaceAll(regex,"$1X");
```

Strings should not be concatenated using '+' in a loop. If, how ever, you want to stick to that approach you should only itereate to the largest number multiple of three which is less than your input length. You also need to append possiblly not appended chars if your input length is not a multiple of three after the loop:

```
String a = "abcabcabcab";
String ans = "";

for (int j = 0; j < a.length() / 3 * 3; j += 3) {
    ans += a.substring(j, j+2) + 'X';
}

ans += a.substring(ans.length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String replaceEvery3rdChar(String input) 
{
     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) 
     {
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
        {
          result.append("X");
        } 
        else
        {
          result.append(input.charAt(i));
        }
     }
     return result.toString();
  }
```